Go: air isn't building my project after I moved the files to subdirectories
I'm very new to Go and I just followed the air guide to getting my app live-reloading, which worked, but when I then tried to move my Go files to subdirectories to follow the advice in the "Let's Go Further" ebook, air stopped working.

I eventually figured it out with a lot of Googling:

I had to modify the cmd parameter in my .air.toml file to point at the directory where I had moved my main.go file:

cmd = "go build -o ./tmp/main ./cmd/api/."


I had to update my .air.toml file to list the directories I wanted it to watch for changes:

include_dir = ["cmd", "internal"]


Note there's no leading ./ in the directory names, that tripped me up for a while.

So my backend directory now looks like this:
bin/
cmd/
  api/
internal/
  data/
migrations/
remote/
.air.toml
.gitignore
go.mod
Makefile

And my .air.toml now looks like this:
[build]
bin = "./tmp/main"
cmd = "go build -o ./tmp/main ./cmd/api/."
include_dir = ["cmd", "internal"]
log = "stdout"

[run]
cmd = "./tmp/main"  # Command to run the binary


With this setup, you will be able to cd into cmd/api and run air.
This will allow you to use air with multiple executables under cmd/** by having an air configuration for each cmd.
Here is what the folder structure looks like:
bin/
cmd/
  api/
    .air.toml
  frontend/
    .air.toml
internal/
  data/
migrations/
remote/
.gitignore
go.mod
Makefile

File: cmd/api/.air.toml:
root = "../../"
testdata_dir = "testdata"
tmp_dir = "tmp"

[build]
  args_bin = []
  bin = "tmp/api"
  cmd = "go build -o ./tmp/api ."

